# Python: name 'variable' is local and global

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables, global-variables

I've been having a problem recently when trying to make a timer app in python. As I'm pretty new, so I've only just started getting into functions.

I know that, one can't access variables within functions without a global statement but when I try that I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: name 'seconds' is local and global
```

from the following code:

```
def countdown(minutes, seconds):
    global minutes
    global seconds
    while (minutes*60) > 0 or seconds > 0:
        seconds -= 1
        if seconds < 0:
            seconds = 59
            minutes = minutes - 1
        time.sleep(1)

    print(minutes)
    print(seconds)
```

I'd really appreciate any help :)

Comment: In python3 the error message is `SyntaxError: name 'minutes' is parameter and global` which explains the problem of your code better.

Comment: How would I go about fixing the issue? I'm pretty new to understanding error messages so I don't fully understand that error

Comment: Depending on your needs, either remove `global` declarations or remove the parameters of your function. I would start by removing `global`s.

Comment: I tried that but when I removed the global declarations I get a new error message: `NameError: name 'minutes' is not defined`

Comment: ***new error message:***: This can't be the case, you clearly have `def countdown(minutes, ...` which defines `minutes`.

Comment: Outside of the function, I have a variable named output which uses the `minutes` variable: `output = '%02d : %02d' % (minutes, seconds)` and when I run this the error `NameError: name 'minutes' is not defined` appears

Answer (score 2):

Each function has its own scope.
Generally, variables are either passed as parameters, or declared inside.

Here you do both. You pass them first, and then try fetching them from the outside as globals.

Use globals only if you have a good reason (predefined parameter list that you can't change, etc...). You don't need them here.

It should work like this:

```
import time

def countdown(minutes, seconds):
    while minutes > 0 or seconds > 0:
        print(minutes, seconds)
        time.sleep(1)
        seconds -= 1
        if seconds < 0:
            seconds = 59
            minutes = minutes - 1
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    countdown(0, 5)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it seems to work but I can't figure out how to integrate it into my code. I have an output variable which I need to use later on with Tkinter. Sorry, I find this hard to explain but I'll just put the whole code here as it would be easier for you to be able to read: https://github.com/lewis-cooper/Pomodoro-Timer/blob/master/pomodoro_timer.py

Comment: Hmm, looking at your code the original question is not the problem. Tkinter has a class StringVar that is connecter to root, that's what you're supposed to use (otherwise you won't be able to update your text).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is the best solution, but since you want to integrate the function into tkinter app, you can use timeRemaining['text'] = output and root.update() in your while loop inside the countdown function.

Like this:

```py
def countdown(minutes, seconds):
    while (minutes*60) > 0 or seconds > 0:
            seconds -= 1
            if seconds < 0:
                seconds = 59
                minutes = minutes - 1
            time.sleep(1)
            output = '%02d : %02d' % (minutes, seconds)
            timeRemaining['text'] = output
            root.update()
```